# I need a vector to be in a specific place

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this unity game, I'm writing a mod for there are humans and I'm making a human explode once it is killed but the explosion defaults to the same place on the map,

```
ModAPI.OnDeath += (sender, life) => {
    ExplosionCreator.Explode(new ExplosionCreator.ExplosionParameters
        {
            Position = new Vector3(5, 5, 5),
            CreateParticlesAndSound = true,
            LargeExplosionParticles = false,
            DismemberChance = 0.1f,
            FragmentForce = 8,
            FragmentationRayCount = 32,
            Range = 10
        });
```

How would I make it so that the position of the explosion is always wherever the human died?

Comment: Dont set the position to be 5,5,5?

Comment: It was 0, 0, 0 but it made no difference it just changes the set location of the explosion but I'd like it to be where the entity is at that moment in time.

Comment: Is sender the human?  If so, perhaps it has a position property which you can set as the Position in your explosion parameters object

Comment: use are using lamda expression, with delegate. Do you understand it ?

Comment: So. You have to tell it which position the entity was at. Not just give it a fixed point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea how your modding framework works but to me it looks like sender is the Entity that died

```
ModAPI.OnDeath += (sender, life) => {
ExplosionCreator.Explode(new ExplosionCreator.ExplosionParameters
    {
        //Assuming you can use default Unity syntax
        Position = sender.gameObject.transform.position,
        CreateParticlesAndSound = true,
        LargeExplosionParticles = false,
        DismemberChance = 0.1f,
        FragmentForce = 8,
        FragmentationRayCount = 32,
        Range = 10
    });
```

As I said I don't know what game or framework you are using but at least this concept should give you the wished result

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly except sender had to be changed to life. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the human position on the map and set it in the position parameter. You cant set it to 5, 5, 5 cause it is taking positions relative to the map, not the entity.